# Humbleness and humility, are these words perfect synonyms?

Tags: synonyms

Is there a difference between the words "humbleness" and "humility", or are they perfectly interchangeable?

Comment: See [this](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/humbleness).

Comment: Please share your reasearch in the question, not in the comments. You ask about *perfect synonyms* so it's not clear why you think they may be.  If you do include the dictionary definitions and the reason for asking, you'll get better answers.

Comment: The idea that there is such a thing as a perfect synonym ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When describing a *person* and their quality of humility, they are interchangeable. 'Humility' is used far more in literature as [this ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=humility%2C%20humbleness&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chumility%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chumbleness%3B%2Cc0) demonstrates. I'm a native British English speaker, and I've personally never encountered the word 'humbleness' in everyday use.

However, one can also describe an inanimate object, or an abstract as being 'humble' - for example, "a humble upbringing", or "the humble sandwich". Such things could not be described as having 'humility' as this is a human trait, so the quality they possess would be "humbleness".

Comment: I understand the primary intent is to provide the best answer for others but I also think it would be polite to acknowledge when incorporating another's answer into yours, especially when it substantially changes your original answer.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there is a difference and so they are not perfectly interchangeable.

For instance, in addition to the shared "personal quality of a modest self-perception" meaning, *humbleness* can also mean having actual low rank.

[Example](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/humbleness):

"Despite the humbleness of her birth she rose to greatness."